# creating nice numbers - how to deal with numbers < 0 with log10?

Tags: php, math

I put together a function to create "nice numbers" for displaying labels. The function makes use of `log10` to normalize odd numbers. Unfortunately, **`log10` doesn't deal with numbers < 0 but returns NAN**.
Now, I have an "ugly" number like `-2.36`, how to get the nearest nice number, like `-2.3`or `-2.0`?

If I convert it to `2.36` in order to put it thru the function and multiply it by `-1` afterwards, I'd get `-2.4` ---> no go, because it is required that `nice-number > ugly-number`.

Any ideas?

Links to define nice-numbers etc:
http://wiki.tcl.tk/16640
[Algorithm for "nice" grid line intervals on a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361681/algorithm-for-nice-grid-line-intervals-on-a-graph)
[round to nearest nice number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725278/round-to-nearest-nice-number)

Here's my code:

```
function niceNum($range, $round) {
    // $exponent: exponent of range
    // $fraction: fractional part of range
    // $niceFraction: nice, rounded fraction  
    if ($range==0) return 0;

    $exponent = floor(log10($range));
    $fraction = $range / pow(10, $exponent);

    if ($round) {
        if ($fraction < 1.5)
            $niceFraction = 1;
        elseif ($fraction < 3)
            $niceFraction = 2;
        elseif ($fraction < 7)
            $niceFraction = 5;
        else
            $niceFraction = 10;
    } else {
        if ($fraction <= 1)
            $niceFraction = 1;
        elseif ($fraction <= 2)
            $niceFraction = 2;
        elseif ($fraction <= 5)
            $niceFraction = 5;
        else
            $niceFraction = 10;
    }
    return $niceFraction * pow(10, $exponent);
}
```

Comment: May be you need number_format or sprintf?

Comment: @sectus: please explain?

Comment: Why would you round -2.36 up to -2.3? -2.4 or -2 would be correct.

Comment: Please, define "nice" and "ugly" numbers. What is "nice", what is "ugly"?

Comment: @shapeshifter: $nice > $ugly => -2.4 is wrong. If e.g. I have a range from -2.36 to -1.84, I'd like to have: -2.36 -2.3 -2.2 -2.1 -2.0 -1.9 -1.84

Comment: Have you link to learn about this definition? Or bring more examples.

Comment: @sectus: see my edit in a few secs...

Comment: @michi, what about generating the whole range even if it includes 2.4 then trim the ends if they are outside the range.

Comment: @shapeshifter: ok, that's a good idea!

Comment: Range must be a difference max between min. Is it? So you can't get negative number.